# How to write a Bazel BUILD file for this Boost.Build Jamfile?

Tags: c++, gradle, bazel, boost-build

I am trying to migrate from Boost.Build to Bazel build system. I need to write a Jamfile for a directory that is building a library.

The Jamfile I have is

```
project : usage-requirements <include>$(PROJECT_INSTALL) 
<linkflags>-lboost_system
;

lib CommonDataStructures : [ glob *.cpp ] : <link>static ;

install libCommonDataStructures
  : CommonDataStructures
  : <install-type>LIB
    <variant>release:<location>"$(PROJECT_INSTALL)/lib"
    <variant>debug:<location>"$(PROJECT_INSTALL)/libdebug"
  : release debug
  ;
```

How do I write a BUILD file for Bazel?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I have no experience with Boost.Build, but I'll try.

The BUILD file will probably contain just:

```
cc_library(
  name = "common_data_structures",
  srcs = glob(["*.cpp"]),
)
```

And to build it just run `bazel build //:common_data_structures`. Bazel will produce both static library and shared library, and when other cc_library or cc_binary will depend on it, it will be by default statically linked. Take a look at our [c++ rules documentation](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/c-cpp.html) to see all the attributes. Was this helpful at all?

Comment: this is not helpful at all